# Cron expression that starts at 1am and runs every 10 minutes on weekdays

Tags: quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I currently have a Quartz cron trigger that runs every 10 minutes Monday to Friday with this expression:

```
0 0/10 * ? * Mon-Fri
```

I am looking for a way to start the schedule from 1am on Monday and then run it every 10 minutes for the remainder of the week. Is this possible with a single cron expression?

An expression such as `0 0/10 1-23 ? * Mon-Fri` would start at 1am but not run between 12 midight and 1am on subequent days, which is not what I need.

Comment: What time does it run last on Friday?

Comment: It last runs at midnight on Friday

Comment: Worst case, you could put a check in your code not to execute between midnight and 1 am on Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on Quartz, but couldn't you schedule your job twice?

```
0 0/10 1-23 ? * Mon
0 0/10 * ? * Tue-Fri
```

Comment: Yes this might be my fall back position if it can't be expressed as a single expression.

Answer (score 0):

The cron expression you told works fine i guess. You can verify it here http://www.cronmaker.com/ by entering your cron expression `0 0/10 * ? * Mon-Fri` and check the next schedule.

Comment: Yes that is my current cron expression and works as expected.  However I want to modifiy it to start at 1am on Monday only and not 12 midnight as it is currently.

Comment: Then, as per my knowledge i guess you should go with two expressions `0 0/10 1-23 ? * Mon 
0 0/10 * ? * Tue-Fri` . This could be the only possible solution to your problem.

Comment: And yes as what @Gilbert Le Blanc  answered.